# Слияние упорядоченных списков вставкой

Tags: c++, список

Доброго времени суток.
Даны два упорядоченных списка, нужно вставить элементы первого списка во второй так, чтобы он остался упорядоченным.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно реализовать функцию вставки? В данный момент программа просто вставляет подряд  все элементы первого списка во второй.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <locale.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;
const int X = 10;//Количество элементов в списке
const int N = 100;//Спектр значения элемента

struct List
{
    int info;
    List* pred, * next;
};

void CreateListR(List*& h, List*& t, int n)//Создаёт список с рандомными значениями
{
    h = new List;
    t = new List;
    List* last = h;
    h->next = t;
    t->pred = h;
    List* p = NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        p = new List;
        p->info = rand() % (2 * N) - N;
        t->pred = p;
        last->next = p;
        p->pred = last;
        p->next = t;
        last = p;
    }
}
void ListOut(List* h, List* t)//Выводит список на экран
{
    List* p = h->next;
    while (p != t)
    {
        cout << setw(6) << p->info;
        p = p->next;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void RemoveList(List* h, List* t)//Удаляет список из памяти
{
    List* p = h;
    while (p != t)
    {
        p = p->next;
        delete p->pred;
    }
    delete p;
}

void Sort(List* h, List* t)//Сортирует список по возрастанию
{
    List* left = h;
    List* right = h->next;
    while (left->next != t)
    {
        while (right != t)
        {
            if ((left->info) > (right->info))
            {
                swap(left->info, right->info);
            }
            right = right->next;
        }
        left = left->next;
        right = left->next;
    }
}


void involve(List* h1, List* t1, List* h2, List* t2)//Вставляет элементы списка L2 в список L1 так, 
{                                                   //что список L1 остаётся упорядоченным по возрастанию               
//Вот тут у меня возникла проблема
    List* temp1 = h1;
    List* temp2 = h2;
    while (temp1 != t1)
    {
        List* inv = new List;
        if ((temp1->info) > (temp2->info))
        {
            inv = temp2->next;
            temp2->next = new List;
            temp2->next->info = temp1->info;
            temp2->next->next = inv;
        }
        temp1 = temp1->next;
        temp2 = temp2->next;
    }
}


int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    srand(time(NULL));
    List* h1 = NULL; List* t1 = NULL;//L1
    List* h2 = NULL; List* t2 = NULL;//L2
    CreateListR(h1, t1, X);
    CreateListR(h2, t2, X);
    cout << "List L1:" << endl;
    Sort(h1, t1);
    ListOut(h1, t1);
    cout << "List L2:" << endl;
    Sort(h2, t2);
    ListOut(h2, t2);
    involve(h1, t1, h2, t2);
    cout << "Refresh List L2: " << endl;
    ListOut(h2, t2);
    cout << endl;
    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

[image: Итог программы:]

Comment: вставить или обьеденить?

Comment: @ARHovsepyan вставить

Comment: самое банальное: по 1ому вставляем в 1ый список элементы из 2ого, для этого просто бежим по первому списку в поиске подходящего места(тк списки упорядочены бегать каждый раз по всему не придётся, а значит сложность O(n))

Comment: @ARHovsepyan а в чём по-вашему тут заключается разница между вставкой и объединением(если не предполагать, что дано идиотское задание найти место куда можно засунуть сразу весь 2ой список)

Comment: @tim bars , по нашему разница в том же, что и принято понимать..Вставка и обьединение разные понятия.

Comment: Вы уверены, что в самом деле хотите использовать  списки с 2-мя лишними элементами (первым и последним)? Обычно указатели на голову и хвост списка  адресуют реально используемые элементы.

Comment: Всем большое спасибо, проблема решена.

Comment: Если еще будете интересоваться списками, имеет смысл ознакомиться с их [реализацией в Linux](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/list.h)

Comment: @avp Спасибо за информацию, весьма полезно, это должно помочь мне в будущем.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как и всегда с упорядоченными списками достаточно одного прохода по всем элементам обеих списков.

Насколько я понял задачу, речь идет о вставке копии элементов списка 1 в список 2
(иначе не понятно, что делать с указателями не голову и хвост списка 1 после вызова `involve()`).

```
void involve(List* h1, List* t1, List* h2, List* t2)//Вставляет элементы списка L1 в список L2 так, 
{                                                   //что список L2 остаётся упорядоченным по возрастанию

  /*
    Автор использует необычный список с фиктивными первым и последним элементами.
    (я впервые столкнулся с таким)
    Однако, такая структура оказалась весьма удобной для операций вставки
  */
  List *p1 = h1->next;
  List *p2 = h2->next;

  while (p1 != t1) {
    List *inv = new List;
    inv->info = p1->info; // сделаем копию элемента из списка 1

    // найдем элемент списка 2, 
    // перед которым надо вставлять копию очередного элемента списка 1
    while (p2 != t2 && p1->info >= p2->info) 
      p2 = p2->next;

    // обратите внимание, если список 2 уже пройден, 
    // т.е. все оставшиеся в списке 1 элементы больше всех из списка 2,
    // то p2 сохраняется, он указывает на  хвост списка 2, перед которым и надо вставлять
    inv->next = p2;
    inv->pred = p2->pred;
    p2->pred->next = inv;
    p2->pred = inv;

    p1 = p1->next;
  }

}
```

Следует отметить, что вставляя список 1 в список 2, я руководствовался текстом вопроса, а не противоречащими ему (вставить L2 в L1) комментариями в тексте программы автора.

Answer (score 0):

Можно предложить функцию вставки в упорядоченный список нового элемента с сохранением сортировки.

```
void sIns(List** head, List* new_node)  
{  
    Node* current;  
    // Список пустой
    if (*head == NULL || (*head)->info >= new_node->info)  
    {  
        new_node->next = *head;  
        *head = new_node;  
    }  
    else
    {  
        // Ищем место для вставки
        current = *head;  
        while (current->next!=NULL &&  
            current->next->info < new_node->info)  
        {  
            current = current->next;  
        }  
        new_node->next = current->next;  
        current->next = new_node;  
    }  
}
```

Далее проходим по всем элементам списка 2 и каждый вставляем.

```
temp=*head2;
while (temp->next!=NULL)  
            {  
                sIns(&head1, temp->info}
                current = current->next;  
            }
```